# How to get a 3d scan as txt from Rawlog file?

Tags: mobile-robot-toolkit

I'm new to c++ programming and I am currently trying to work with kinect and  Hokuyo sensors with mrpt. The rawlog-grabber app allows me to get scan from both sensors and I can get the 2D-scan (Hokuyo) as txt file with rawlog-edit. But I can't seem to be able to get the 3D-scan (kinect) as a txt file, I don't know if it is even possible: rawlog-edit doesn't show any kind of function to do so.

Thanks in advance for your consideration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the `--txt-externals` flag to rawlog-edit. It was [implemented](https://github.com/MRPT/mrpt/blob/master/apps/rawlog-edit/rawlog-edit_main.cpp#L92-L96) in 2016, so the latest releases (e.g. 1.5.5, 1.5.6, etc.) should come with that feature:

```
rawlog-edit -i input.rawlog --externalize --txt-externals
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This command create a folder with each images and the range scans separately as txt. Worked like a charm.